# Ubuntu 22.04 WiFi getting disconnected and cannot reconnect back

Tags: networking, 22.04, thinkpad, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 22.04 on Thinkpad X1 gets disconnected from WiFi and cannot reconnect back untill reboot. The corresponding log entry is:

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not associated and the session protection is over already...
```

Kernel Device: `+pci:0000:00:14.3`

This issue also gets triggered if the bluetooth is turned off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered this problem and typically reconnect by restarting my hotspot instead of rebooting.  Not much of an answer.  From long ago work on an antique system, I believe that Ubuntu doesn't detect the disconnect and doesn't signal a need/attempt to renegotiate the connection.  I don't have enough Ubuntu experience to know how to prove this nor how to really fix it.

Comment: This is not really an answer, and should rather be a comment under the post.